# Replacing 3-way switch in 4-way circuit with an occupancy switch - not working correctly

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch, motion-sensor

I'm trying to replace one of the 3-way switches in a 4-way switch circuit with a 3-way occupancy sensor.

Here's my current wiring for the occupancy sensor:[image]

And here's the current wiring for the other 3-way switch
[image]

I haven't touched the 4-way switch.

Before I changed any wiring, the black screw on both 3-way switches was connected to the black wire.

Here is the current behavior of the circuit:

When occupancy sensor is OFF:

- 4-way switch does not function
- If the 4-way switch is in the OFF position:

  - 3-way switch does nothing
- If the 4-way switch is in the ON position:

  - 3-way switch works, but only if I switch it slowly. If I switch rapidly, it only works every other time the switch changes.

When occupancy sensor is ON:

- 3-way switch works properly
- When the 4-way switch is switched, the lights flicker off while the switch is in between positions.

Any thoughts on what I've screwed up with my wiring?

Comment: What make and model is the occupancy sensor?

Comment: Some of the occupancy sensors require the neutral. The 2nd switch only has 2 wires going to it is it a digital model that doesn't require the travelers? If this is the case you will need the same brand and model for the system to communicate to the other switches.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel it's a Lutron MS-OPS5MH-LA

Comment: @EdBeal there are three wires in the second switch, I just have the one of the travellers and the hot wired together with the yellow wire, as instructed by the occupancy switch's installation directions.

Comment: Can we have photos of the inside of the occupancy sensor box and the four-way box?

Answer (score 1):

You generally have 3 conductors in a 3/4-way switch loop, and you can't misuse ground as a conductor.    That leaves Only two ways to do it (short of a relay and low-voltage wiring):

### Smart switches in the auxiliary locations

Obtain smart switches designed to be "remotes" for the main motion sensor and interact with it electronically, either using 1 wire as a data line, or wireless via power-line signaling or radio.

### Very lucky topology

This can only work, if

- supply power comes in to the light, the switches are all one spur, and the motion sensor is in the first box.
- supply power comes into the same switch box as the spur to the light, and the sensor is in that box.
- the essential interconnections are in conduit, and you can pull more wires.

Otherwise you'll have a spot where you need 4 wires, and you only have 3 in the walls.

Your sensor needs three wires coming in: always-hot, switched-hot from the switch, and neutral for the light's current return.  The sensor doesn't need neutral, but the light does, so inevitably neutral must come back this way.

http://www.lutron.com/TechnicalDocumentLibrary/369488.pdf

It does not support a 3-way switch.  It supports a plain switch which switches between 'open' and always-hot or switched-hot. If it is placed in one position and the one other position was a 3-way switch, then they have you rewire the 3-way to be a plain switch.

Since you have two remaining positions with manual switches, those two positions must together emulate the behavior of a plain 1-way switch.   They way you do that is the classical 3-way circuit.  The 4-way switch needs to be swapped out for a 3-way.  Which you happen to have spare. However, if supply to the light also travels the switch wires, you'll need 4 wires in that segment:

- always-hot for the smart switch
- messenger 1
- messenger 2
- neutral to return current from the light

This is one more than a traditional n-way, installed with the usual 14/3, and you can't retrofit a consuctor.

This does work if your topology is just right: the two remaining physical switches are on a spur.  In that case you won't need to carry lighting power (i.e. The neutral) between switches and you'll have enough wires.

Comment: I found [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/20840/how-can-i-replace-a-4-way-mechanical-switch-with-occupancy-sensors) which has an answer that seems to indicate via [this document](http://www.lutron.com/TechnicalDocumentLibrary/048435.pdf) that this **is** in fact possible if I were to purchase two of these [companion switches](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Lutron-Maestro-8-Amp-Multi-Location-Companion-Switch-White-MA-AS-WH/205863253). Is that correct?

Comment: Ha!  I fell to the narrow thinking I am usually warning others about!   Yes, if you go smart switxhes in all locations, you are sympatico. Then instead of 2 messengers you have just 1 comms wire (or 0 if it uses signal-over-power or wireless).