# 4 way switch motion sensor

Tags: electrical, lighting, motion-sensor

There is a stairwell in our house, which is currently lit by a fixture controlled by three switches: a 4-way and two 3-ways. I want to install motion sensors to have lights turn on once motion is detected. any idea how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Motion sensor at the light? At just the 4-way switch? At every switch?

Comment: The question is unclear, but similar to this 11 year old one. Likely "smarter smart switches" offer more options these days so **not** voting to close as duplicate. Close to voting to close as unclear, though... https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/20840/18078

Comment: I suspect that you mean a switch plate with 4 switches, rather than a rotary switch with 4 positions, or 4 switches controlling one light.  Please clarify.

Comment: Do you intend the sensor to turn the light on and off, or just turn it on ?

Comment: @RohitGupta I think it is 3 switches control one light, a "3-way" at each end and a "4-way" in the middle. But even with that, still unclear as to where OP wants a motion sensor (or possibly multiple sensors).

Comment: @RohitGupta everywhere but North America, a "3-way" switch (DPDT) - in NA, called 4-way. Works with NA-lexicon "3-way switches" (SPDT) which everywhere else in the world calls 2-way switches.

Comment: Do you want motion sensing at all switch locations, or just a subset of them?